# Trying to set a default quantity, if no quantity exists

Tags: php, yii

WHat I'm trying to do is set the quantity of tokens to 0 if there is no existing token amount in my database. However the code I ahve below doesn't work, although it's pretty much identical to what I use for buy and spend functions which work perfectly.

```
public function actionIndex() {
    $_id = Yii::app()->user->getId();
    $model = Tokens::model()->findByAttributes(array('UserID' => $_id));
    if ($model === null)
        $defaultqty = 0;
        $model->TokenAmount = ($model->TokenAmount + $defaultqty);
        $model->save(false);
        throw new CHttpException(404, "yea it's broke, deal with it");

    $this->render('index', array(
        'model' => $model,
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$model = Tokens::model()->findByAttributes(array('UserID' => $_id));
    if ($model === null) ...
```

After if you have no model object inside the $model variable. You should create new model before working with it.

```
$model = Tokens::model()->findByAttributes(array('UserID' => $_id));
    if ($model === null) {
        $model = new Tokens;
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to use `CActiveRecord beforeSave()` method

```
class Tokens extends MyActiveModel {
    private $defaultTokenAmount = 0;
    ...
    public function beforeSave() {
        if (empty($this->TokenAmount)) {
            $this->TokenAmount = $defaultTokenAmount;
        }

        return parent::beforeSave();
    }
}
```